# Using Spring Converter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a spring mvc web application lately using thymeleaf as view engine, hibernate for dao and spring security.

When i was making my controllers, i faced a situation :

i have a `Notification` entity, which has a compound primary key `NotificationPK(CreationDate+UserID)` : creationDate is the **time** of the creation of the notification

i want to show the content of a notification using url **/notif/{creationDate}**.  (i don't need to pass the user id since i can retrieve it using spring security)

the problem is creation date is a timestamp , so i have to use a Spring converter (i was told so)

But the thing is, i get the general idea of the converter, but i don't know how to make it in this situation, i don't get how this converter works in the controller

can someone please help with an example and an explanation on how to add that converter to the controller, and how does that converter works

**EDIT**

Is this code correct :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doctor/notification/{creationDate}")
    public ModelAndView getNotification(@PathVariable( "creationDate" ) @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat( pattern = "YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" ) Timestamp creationDate){
        if (doctor==null) setCurrentUser();
        if (creationDate==null) throw new NoSuchNotificationException();
        NotificationPK pk = new NotificationPK();
        pk.setRecipient(doctor.getIdPers());
        pk.setCreationDate(creationDate); //.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring you can use this:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/notif/{creationDate}")
  public String getnotification(@PathVariable( "creationDate" ) @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat( pattern = "MMMM dd, yyyy" ) java.util.Calendar creationDate){
     //here creation Date is your Calendar object
  }
```

Comment: the creationdate actually contains the time too (i'll edit that)

Comment: I believe that this works with Calendar and Date so I am not sure about Timestamp. You can try it and see what happens.